# Vue 3: Cannot get or assign a value to ref of ref?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I encountered an interesting scenario where I had a ref to an object within my own ref to an object. But the inner ref's value was undefined and the value property cannot be dereferenced at all. Upon more testing I found the same behavior for null. It seems like the inner ref is evaluating so the .value cannot be reached?

Is this by design? Is there anyway to get access to the .value?

https://jsfiddle.net/CodeVirtue/mjf2yg5d/

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

let options = {
  setup: function () {
    const outer = ref({
      innerUndefined: ref(undefined),
      innerNull: ref(null),
      innerObject: ref({}),
      innerZero: ref(0)
    });
    const outerUndefined = ref(undefined);
    const outerNull = ref(null);
    // Setting innerUndefined fails
    console.log('Attempting to set innerUndefined.value');
    try {
        outer.value.innerUndefined.value = { 'test': 1 };
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('FAIL: ' + error.toString());
    }
    // Setting innerNull fails
    console.log('Attempting to set innerNull.value');
    try {
        outer.value.innerNull.value = { 'test': 2 };
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('FAIL: ' + error.toString());
    }
    // Setting innerZero succeeds
    console.log('Attempting to set innerObject.value');
    outer.value.innerObject.value = { 'test': 3 };
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting innerZero succeeds
    console.log('Attempting to set innerZero.value');
    outer.value.innerZero.value = { 'test': 4 };
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting outerUndefined succeeds
    console.log('Attempting to set outerUndefined.value');
    outerUndefined.value = { 'test': 5 };
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting outerNull succeeds
    console.log('Attempting to set outerNull.value');
    outerNull.value = { 'test': 6 };
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    return {};
  }
};

Vue.createApp(options).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">See the console</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need nested `ref()`? What if you replace the `innerUndefined: ref(undefined)` with `innerUndefined: undefined` along with the other props? Ref properties of reactive objects get unwrapped automatically upon access [https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations @MaxMartynov. I am not solving this for my use case, as I have already refactored the codebase I am working in. The point of this post is pointing out an inconsistency with Vue JS. I found through experimentation the only way I have been able to get the above scenario to work is to pass the outer ref to toRaw(), for example: toRaw(outer.value).innerUndefined.value works, but outer.value.innerUndefined.value does not. unref() doesn't even fix it. Smells like a Vue JS bug...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to reduce the number of key/value pairs and work with one at a time. Then build multiple assertions (FAIL 1, FAIL 2, FAIL 3), each being a different level of the fully qualified object in the catch. Having error isn't enough detail to troubleshoot. FAIL 1 being outer.value. FAIL 2 being outer.value.innerNull. FAIL 3 being outer.value.innerNull.value.

Right now, you have error in the catch. You need the object variable in the catch to understand the failure. This way, you know if outer is undefined, or if outer.value is undefined, or if outer.value.innerNull is undefined or if outer.value.innerNull.value is undefined. Each level needs a value to allow the fully qualified object to have a value. Right now, your try is failing on the fully qualified value, but it's probably an ancestor object that is undefined.

If you are building try/catch blocks for all use cases (meaning exhaustive), my suggestion is to write a function that loops through the object levels and return the level that is the culprit as well as the variable (object fully qualified name).  And then fail the entire JSON on the first failure.  Or loop through the objects that fail and print one failure.

Example:

Notice that ancestor objects (ie: outer and outer.value) have a value of [object: Object], so those levels seem fine.  I got the 3rd level to fail.  Repeat this methodology for the rest of your use cases.

```
const { ref } = Vue;

let options = {
    setup: function () {
    const outer = ref({
      innerUndefined: ref(undefined)
      // innerNull: ref(null),
      // innerObject: ref({}),
      // innerZero: ref(0)
    });
    const outerUndefined = ref(undefined);
    const outerNull = ref(null);
    // Setting innerUndefined fails
    console.log('Attempting to set innerUndefined.value');
    try {
        outer.value.innerUndefined.value = { 'test': 1 };
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('FAIL: ' + outer.value.innerUndefined);
    }
    // Setting innerNull fails
    // console.log('Attempting to set innerNull.value');
    // try {
    //  outer.value.innerNull.value = { 'test': 2 };
    // }
    // catch (error) {
    //  console.log('FAIL: ' + error.toString());
    // }
    // Setting innerZero succeeds
    // console.log('Attempting to set innerObject.value');
    // outer.value.innerObject.value = { 'test': 3 };
    // console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting innerZero succeeds
    // console.log('Attempting to set innerZero.value');
    // outer.value.innerZero.value = { 'test': 4 };
    // console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting outerUndefined succeeds
    // console.log('Attempting to set outerUndefined.value');
    // outerUndefined.value = { 'test': 5 };
    // console.log('SUCCESS');
    // Setting outerNull succeeds
    // console.log('Attempting to set outerNull.value');
    // outerNull.value = { 'test': 6 };
    console.log('SUCCESS');
    return {};
  }
};

Vue.createApp(options).mount('#app');
```